# nsnotification not working in skscene

Tags: sprite-kit, nsnotification, skscene

I am writing a sprite kit game and I have in app purchase in my game. I implement the in

app purchase in file IAPHelper.m(IAPHelper.m is a subclass of NSObject), and if the

purchase success, it will post a  nsnotification,the code is like:

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
NSLog(@"post a notification");

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier     userInfo:nil];

 }
```

And in MyScene.m(MyScene.m is a subclass of SKScene), I add an observer for the notification:

```
   -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
     if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ok:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];

       }
    return self;

    }
  - (void)ok:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSLog(@"Ok, I got it");

     }
```

And What I am trying to do is IAPHelper.m post the notification, and MyScene.m receive it and respond to it. But the result is  MyScene.m seems not receiving the notification and thus the code

```
    - (void)ok:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Ok, I got it");
     }
```

is not being called. but if I put the observer in my ViewController.m( subclass of UIViewController), it works. My question is: can skscene receive notification from any object? And if it can, how to implement it.

Many Thanks if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Your code is badly formatted, and 'it does not work' is a very vague problem statement. Try to explain what you've done, what you expect and what you are actually getting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have re-edit my code and my question, many thanks if you can look at it again.